# Pyplot Keep Text Size While Zooming

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to have some text in a pyplot figure, and be able to zoom in on it without it changing scale. See below example of the plot, what I'd like to happen, and what actually happens.
Code reproducing the error:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot((0, 0, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1, 1))
plt.text(0, 0, 'Test', fontsize=150)
plt.show()
```

Example pictures:
[image: The Example Plot]
[image: What I Would Like To Happen When Zooming]
[image: What Actually Happens]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Text in matplotlib is defined in points. Points is an absolute quantity, proportional to inches. Text will hence always have the same size.

Here you would like to define text in data coordinates. This is possible by converting the text to a path first, then adding that path to the axes. It's done via a [`TextPath`](https://matplotlib.org/api/textpath_api.html), which is subsequently converted to a [`PathPatch`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.PathPatch.html?highlight=pathpatch)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.textpath import TextPath
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch

plt.plot((0, 0, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1, 1))

tp = TextPath((0,0), "Test", size=0.4)
plt.gca().add_patch(PathPatch(tp, color="black"))

plt.show()
```

[image]