# Setting TextPath length and width independently in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below is the plot I generated using axes.text option,

`ax[0].text(row.TIMESTAMP, row.HIGH+(0.1*width),row['candlestick_pattern'], fontsize=5, rotation='vertical')`
[image]

I'm trying to achieve the same output using TextPath and PathPatch, in order to increase/decrease the font size when I zoom in/out of the plot, and below is the code I have (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285103/matplotlib-rotating-a-patch) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57235339/pyplot-keep-text-size-while-zooming) )

```
textPath = TextPath((data_coord[1], -data_coord[0]), row['candlestick_pattern'], size=2)
pathPatch = PathPatch(textPath, color="black")
transform = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(90) + ax[0].transData
pathPatch.set_transform(transform)
ax[0].add_patch(pathPatch)
```

Output with this is
[image]

You could see that the text is cramped into a very small region and its not what I want. I would want to set the font size to a smaller value and increase the width (in vertical mode - height) of the TextPath. Is that possible?

Below is the complete code with which we can reproduce the problem for the dataset [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7e5a49c20e3b2cdd3862efbdc55510f020220406044139/c6a42b)

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.textpath import TextPath
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc
from matplotlib import transforms as tf

import pandas as pd

plotDf = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
plotDf.reset_index(inplace=True)
del plotDf['TIMESTAMP']
del plotDf['TOTTRDQTY']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

candlestick_ohlc(ax,plotDf.values,width=0.6, \
                 colorup='green', colordown='red', alpha=0.8)

maxHigh = plotDf['HIGH'].max()
minLow = plotDf['LOW'].min()
width = maxHigh - minLow
threshold = (width)*0.6

for idx, row in plotDf.iterrows():
    if (row['candlestick_pattern'] != 'NO_PATTERN'):
        if (row.HIGH < (threshold+minLow)):
            data_coord = (idx, row.HIGH+(0.1*width))
            #ax.text(idx, row.HIGH+(0.1*width), row['candlestick_pattern'], fontsize=5, rotation='vertical')
        else:
            data_coord = (idx, row.LOW-(0.4*width))
            #ax.text(idx, row.LOW-(0.4*width), row['candlestick_pattern'], fontsize=5, rotation='vertical')

        textPath = TextPath((data_coord[1], -data_coord[0]), row['candlestick_pattern'], size=2)
        pathPatch = PathPatch(textPath, color="black")
        transform = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(90) + ax.transData
        pathPatch.set_transform(transform)
        ax.add_patch(pathPatch)

fig.autofmt_xdate()
fig.tight_layout()
fig.suptitle("test", fontsize=16)
fig.set_size_inches(10.5, 10.5)

plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.95) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you add the data you're using for that plot? Just to make things easier

Comment: Hello, I have shared the data file in [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7e5a49c20e3b2cdd3862efbdc55510f020220406044139/c6a42b)..
It has the data for OHLC charts and the strings are from "candlestick_pattern" column. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your problem is a scaling problem. Messing around with `.scale(x,y)`, `ax.set_xlim` and `ax.set_ylim` might allow you to "unsqueeze" the text. You can also try to set an anchor for your plot like done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557608/unable-to-rotate-a-matplotlib-patch-object-about-a-specific-point-using-rotate-a):

```
ts = ax.transData
coords = ts.transform([0,0]) #<-anchor
tr = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(coords[0],coords[1],90).scale(1,3) #<- scale
t = ts + tr
#<extra code>
pathPatch = PathPatch(textPath, color="black", transform = t)
```

---

### EDIT

I tried many things, but I couldn't find a good way of doing it. I'll leave below what I tried and some resources that might help.

The way to properly use `.rotate_deg_around` would be like such:

```
ts = ax.transData
# ts = fig.dpi_scale_trans #this guy uses the fig scale, if you're interested
coords = ts.transform([data_coord[0],data_coord[1]])
converter = (coords[0]/data_coord[0], coords[1]/data_coord[1])
#plot the anchor points for visualization:
plt.plot(coords[0]/converter[0], coords[1]/converter[1],'xk') 
tr = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(coords[0]/converter[0],coords[1]/converter[1],90).scale(converter[0],converter[1])

pathPatch = PathPatch(textPath, color="black", transform = tr)
ax.add_patch(pathPatch)
```

Nonetheless, the results are still similar to what you had at the beginning:
[image]

It appears that `TextPath` does not behave like it should when using transform. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43915452/13542462) `.get_offset_transform` is used, and it apparently fixes this sort of issue, but I was unable to use it since the plt has a Line type.

Also, you will see that if you increase the `y` axis in `.scale`, you can start to see the text, but it spreads the coordinates as well. One idea you can try is setting a good readable y scale (use `ax.set_ylim` to see your text) and then use that value as a divisor when setting the coordinates for your plot.

There are also some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540449/how-can-i-rotate-a-matplotlib-plot-through-90-degrees) that might serve you.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, mgmussi. I will try this out and update you. In the meantime, I have updated my question with the complete code to plot. Thanks again

Comment: @RajKumar see my updates (sorry I couldn't help too much)

Comment: thanks a lot for your efforts and suggestions, mgmussi. I havent got time to work on top of your suggestions further. Will update here once I progress further on this.

Comment: After checking the matplotlib library code, I found a hack to achieve what I want. While generating the textPath, they get the vertices to place each characters based on the font property and size. I have added couple of new variables "xscale, yscale" using which I modify the vertices. I pass this while creating the TextPath and it is used in TextPath.__init__()->text_to_path.get_text_path() -> get_glyphs_with_font to manipulate the output of font.get_path()